# SQL redshift: Updating a column with data from another table but get an error, why?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am using redshift and have followed this from an example. But I get the error:
[42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "INNER" Position:

```
UPDATE podcast_platform_episode_level
INNER JOIN podcast_country_codes
ON podcast_platform_episode_level.country = podcast_country_codes.country
SET podcast_platform_episode_level.country_label = podcast_country_codes.country_label
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE podcast_platform_episode_level
SET country_label = podcast_country_codes.country_label
FROM podcast_country_codes
WHERE podcast_platform_episode_level.country = podcast_country_codes.country
```

Answer (score 0):

I renamed a column to country_code in podcast_platform_episode_level to help avoid confusion. But still surpised this code below works when the code above does not

```
-- adds country_label data
UPDATE podcast_platform_episode_level
   SET country_label = c.country_label
FROM podcast_country_codes c
WHERE c.country = country_code;
```